# Combining two angularjs expression not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to combine two angularjs expression

1. ```
    <div ng-app="">
       <p>Name :
       <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
       <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
   ```
2. ```
    <div ng-app="">
     <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
    </div>
   ```

by doing this :

```
 <div ng-app="ctrl">
            <p>Enter first numb:<input type="text" ng-model="firstnb"/></p>
            <p>Enter sec numb:<input type="text" ng-model="secnb"/></p>
            <p>Enter operator:<input type="text" ng-model="op"/></p>
          <p>  Result is : {{firstnb}} &nbsp; {{op}} &nbsp; {{secnb}}  = </p>
        </div>
```

but before even calculating the result i am getting this on my browser :
[image: enter code here]

I am a nooby in angular and i have no idea why i am getting the result 
note that : `<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>` is loaded perfectly

Comment: <div ng-app="ctrl">   are you trying to apply controller or is it app name ?

Comment: the app name in the example i saw on w3school the `ng-app=" "`

Comment: are there any console errors? did you define the angular module "ctrl" correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to declare an Angular app and link it to your HTML:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Then, you have to add a controller to your Angular app and use it in your HTML:

JS:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myCtrl">
    <p>Enter first numb:<input type="text" ng-model="firstnb"/></p>
    <p>Enter sec numb:<input type="text" ng-model="secnb"/></p>
    <p>Enter operator:<input type="text" ng-model="op"/></p>
    <p>  Result is : {{firstnb}} &nbsp; {{op}} &nbsp; {{secnb}}  = </p>
</div>
```

See working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16574/)

**EDIT**

I've modified my JSFiddle (see link above) to fit your needs. In the controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.updateResult = function() {
        console.log($scope.op);
        switch($scope.op) {
            case '+':
                $scope.result = Number($scope.firstnb) + Number($scope.secnb)
                break;
        }
    };
});
```

I've only implemented the addition, but I'm sure you'll know how to handle the rest

Comment: thank you for your answer i replace `<div ng-app="myCtrl" >` with '<div ng-app >' and it is working now , but how can i calculate the result ?

Comment: can i do this : `{{  {{firstnb}} {{op}} {{secnb}}   }}` ?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ng-app="ctrl"` you must also defien the module as well. Also i would suggest not to pollute rootScope, instead create a scope using controller.

```
angular.module("ctrl",[]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yokizakibu/edit?html,js,output)**

Else you can just use `ng-app` without module name. but It's recommended to use `module` name and define it using `angular.module`.

```
 <div ng-app>
            <p>Enter first numb:<input type="text" ng-model="firstnb"/></p>
            <p>Enter sec numb:<input type="text" ng-model="secnb"/></p>
            <p>Enter operator:<input type="text" ng-model="op"/></p>
          <p>  Result is : {{firstnb}} &nbsp; {{op}} &nbsp; {{secnb}}  = </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of AngularJS you are using, this is expected.

Check this out may be this will help.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to-src-ng-src-or-action-

Answer (score 0):

check this one its working :--

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
    <p>Enter first numb:<input type="text" ng-model="firstnb"/></p>
    <p>Enter sec numb:<input type="text" ng-model="secnb"/></p>
    <p>Enter operator:<input type="text" ng-model="op"/></p>
    <p>  Result is : {{firstnb}} &nbsp; {{op}} &nbsp; {{secnb}}  = </p>
</div>
```